# How to Use Properties.Settings.Default.Save() values already exits?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am storing some information using properties.settings.default.save() method for the first time and reusing the property value throughout my application.  Actually when uninstall the application and reinstall a newer version of the application, i want to reuse the property values.How can i do it? 
Basically the property will saved in user.config file under my user. if i install newer version of package it creates a new user.config file and uses it but i need to use the existing file which it created for older version package. what to do?

i am using visual studio deployment project for deployment

Comment: @Adrian Faciu: i have accepted a solution but for the rest i didn't get right solution

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028198/can-we-instruct-visual-studio-setup-to-keep-existing-files-for-re-install) on how to make a file permanent. You could create a new settings file and put in AppData folder, in order to avoid problems with the default config file.

Comment: the solution in the link talks about a file that is installed during the msi installation but my scenario is different i am using properties.settings code to save my information at run-time i need to use that file all my successive upgrade version of project